# Check if table exist or not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if the table in database exists, if not create a table with code

```
CREATE TABLE Topics (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    message TEXT
    )
```

and if not create a table. I know I have to use it but I don't know what to use before...

Answer (score 4):

If you're using MySQL, use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Topics (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
message TEXT
)
```

It will create table only if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can show tables before creating new table by run this commands together

```
    USE database_name; -- write your database name
    SHOW TABLES;
```

OR create table if not exit

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Topics (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    message TEXT
    )
```